# lookup value for non empty cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
ColA     ColB   ColC ColD
akhil    cha    sam  rush
34               28
```

I want to extract the value corresponding to  non empty cell . Here non empty cell contain 34 and 28 value. 
so , Formula should idealy extract akhil and sam .

Answer (score 0):

Use the .offset method to get the contents of the cell above the non-empty cell.  I don't know your code, but lets say you are putting the values in an array, then you would loop through the cells you are checking with a "for... each" loop and each time it finds a non-empty cell, use .offset(-1,0).value (or .text) to get the contents of the cell above the non-empty cell.  Then you would need to advance a counter so that the next time it finds a non-empty cell, the contents of the cell above the non-empty cell would be stored in the next available address in the array.

If you use an array, you also need to read up on the Redim command to resize the array before you start storing data in it.  You will require at least two loops, a for... each loop to count the number of non-empty cells so that you can size the array, and a for... each loop to run through the cells and grab the data above the non-empty cells.

Here's an example that uses a small range from D10 to H10 that does what you are asking and just displays the result in the immediate box.  You can do what you want with it.

```
Sub getdata()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim names() As String
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("D10:H10")
a = 0

For Each c In myrange
    If Not c.Value = "" Then a = a + 1
Next c

ReDim names(0 To a - 1)
b = 0
For Each c In myrange
    If Not c.Value = "" Then
        names(b) = c.Offset(-1, 0).Text
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next c

For b = 0 To a - 1
Debug.Print names(b)
Next b

End Sub
```